# How to perform bulk upload in mongoose (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, bulk-load

I am trying to perform bulk upload in node js and `mongodb` is my db,can anyone suggest me some best articles regarding this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Model.collection.insert` or `Model.insertMany` as below where `collections` is array of items in bulk.

```
Model.collection.insert(collections, function (err, models) {
   next(err, models);
});
```

OR,

```
Model.insertMany(collections, function (err, models) {
   next(err, models);
});
```

Mongoose reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Mongo reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

Comment: Hi Aruna,how can i get the xlx sheet data to collections?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert multiple records with batch/bulk insert in mongoose.

```
var arr = [{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'The Empire Strikes Back' }];
Movies.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {});
```

Let's say i have an excel file **employees.xlsx** with following data and i want perform bulk write.

[image: employees.xlsx]

There are several libraries out there for converting excel data to json in node, i use  [xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) but it's personal taste you can use whatever is convenient for you.

Here is a helper i use for reading "/public/employees.xlsx" file.I found the content from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859901/parse-xlsx-with-node-and-create-json).

```
 //** helper/excel-reader.js **//

var excelReader = {};
excelReader.readExcel =  function(filePath){     

  var XLSX = require('xlsx');
  var workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath);
  var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
  var data = [];

  sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) {
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];
    var headers = {};

    for(z in worksheet) {
        if(z[0] === '!') continue;
        //parse out the column, row, and value
        var tt = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(z[i])) {
                tt = i;
                break;
            }
        };
        var col = z.substring(0,tt);
        var row = parseInt(z.substring(tt));
        var value = worksheet[z].v;

        //store header names
        if(row == 1 && value) {
            headers[col] = value;
            continue;
        }

        if(!data[row]) data[row]={};
        data[row][headers[col]] = value;
    }
    //drop those first two rows which are empty
    data.shift();
    data.shift();       
  });
 return data;
}

module.exports = excelReader;
```

Now the employee model somehow looks like this.

```
var mongoose =  require('mongoose');
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

var employee = new Schema({
    name: String,
    adderess: String,
    phonenumber: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', employee);
```

Now let's use the above code so here is my **users.js** route whenever i type "localhost:3000/users" it write the **csv** content to database.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var excelReader = require('../helpers/excel-reader');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Employee = require('../models/employee');

 /* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var employeesJsonArray = excelReader.readExcel('./public/employees.xlsx') 
  Employee.insertMany(employeesJsonArray,function(error, docs) {
    if(error){
      next(error)
    }
    else{
      res.json(docs);//just rendering the document i got
    } 
   });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Wow, Works as expected, Thanks